# Get percentage of RAM Using snmp on freenas

Tags: snmp

I have been trying to get the correct amount of used RAM in freeNAS using SNMP. for now i have been using the generic linux iso: `1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0` but have found that the percentage used is not correct.

For example on my i would do the following `(total ram - avaliable ram) - buffers - cached`

when looking on the system it says 613MB / 6GB 10 %

But when using snmp 70% any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a monitoring tool with SNMP?
I don't know what are buffers and cached but I didn't need to use them to get the correct amount.

```
RAM Total : memTotalReal.0 : .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.5.0
RAM available : memAvailReal.0 : .1.3.6.1.4.1.2021.4.6.0
```

To get percentage: `(( memTotalReal.0-memAvailReal.0 )/memTotalReal.0 )*100`

On Zabbix (my monitoring tool):

```
(last("memTotalReal.0")-last("memAvailReal.0"))/last("memTotalReal.0")*100
```